# File that includes cache manifest automatically includes itself

Tags: html, browser-cache

I have a webpage that serves quite an amount of images that I want to be cached. For that purpose, I have a PHP script that lists the paths of the images I need. The final document looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
uploads/categoriasactuaciones/1.png
uploads/categoriasactuaciones/10.png 
[...]
uploads/riesgos/5.png 
uploads/riesgos/6.png
```

The problem is that the page that has the manifest in the `<html>` tag gets automatically cached and there's where the login logic resides. Is there a way to disable that? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You could trick the browser into believing it is always a different page by adding a random parameter to the query string from wherever you are fetching the page.

For example:

```
<a href="page.html?r=<?= /* your random string here */ ?>">Link here</a>
```

This way the browser won't use the cached page and will issue a new request instead.

This might not work if the page you don't want to cache is your index page. But you could instead set the Cache-Control param in the response header, using functions such as PHP's header() (this depends, of course, upon your programming language):

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

In addition, if you are using a framework you might as well take advantage of the framework's caching configuration.

(Sources: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: The page I am fetching is the index, loaded through CodeIgniter, so it won't work.